# Mutation testing ActiveRecord models with the mutant gem

Tags: rspec2, rspec-rails, rails-activerecord, mutation-testing

I've been trying to get started with mutation testing for our rails app, but haven't been able to get it working - has anyone managed to set this up?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
mutant -I app/models -r foo "Foo#bar" foo_spec.rb
.../trunk/app/models/foo.rb:24:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
```

I've also tried loading the activerecord gem directly using -I, the gem is already installed in the current rvm gemset - I've got a feeling that this'll involve some more complete setup to use the database.yml, unfortunately I can't seem to find anyone who has done this already.

Comment: You use the old mutant by txus? I rewrote it, see http://solnic.eu/2013/01/23/mutation-testing-with-mutant.html for usage example. Rails support ticket is here: https://github.com/mbj/mutant/issues/21

Comment: [michael@imac ~/src/blah/trunk]$ gem list | grep mutant
mutant (0.2.16)
mutant-melbourne (2.0.3) . Thanks for the link though - should get me on the right track

Comment: Looks correct. With the next version I'll have a *rails* section in the Readme. And I'll post a verbose answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Mutant author speaking here.

Under the assumption you are using rails with rspec you can test your models via the following commandline:

`RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec mutant -r ./config/environment --use rspec YourModel`

There is a [README section](https://github.com/mbj/mutant#rails) explaining rails integration.  In case you run into problems please visit to make sure you have the latest instructions.

Comment: thanks for this, I'll give it a go when I get a chance

Comment: Cool. Please provide feedback here (Accepting the answer) when it works.